# Getting timeout while trying to use httpwebrequest to get data from SSL website?

Tags: c#, .net

Long story short I'm trying to reach https://nasdaq.com via httpwebrequest, the code below works on say https://google.com or our company website but it doesn't work on Yahoo or Nasdaq.

Here is the code with comments so it's self-descriptive, thanks in advance!

```
  // I've tried with tls12 or ssl3, still no luck
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;

  // "bumb" is just the variable storing the web address
  HttpWebRequest requestHtm = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(bumb);

 // just in case...
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return 
 true; };


 //below follow a few lines trying to impersonate browser...just in case
   requestHtm.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
   requestHtm.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
   requestHtm.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
   requestHtm.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
   requestHtm.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "en-gb,en;q=0.5";
   requestHtm.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset] = "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
   requestHtm.Timeout = 15000;
   requestHtm.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
   requestHtm.Method = "GET"; 


// using "using" for simplicity...
using (HttpWebResponse responseHtm = (HttpWebResponse)requestHtm.GetResponse())
 {
                        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(responseHtm.GetResponseStream());

                        string text1 = r.ReadToEnd();

  //everything fails here: no messsage box gets shown, just timeout error 

                        MessageBox.Show(text1);

  } //closing the "using"
```

Comment: Btw: this is for 4.5, I am testing on win 8, may try on win 2012 server but need it to work universally...on 4.0 the first line doesn't work but there's way to subsitute with Lambda exp. it seems, still no luck on any framework version.

Comment: What happens if you change `15000` to `150000`?

Comment: ^ will try it now...obviously I'll have to wait way more :).

Comment: @mjwills: It seems like you're right! I just tried on Yahoo with longer timeout and it worked normally...however on Nasdaq when I open it via google chrome it just keeps 'spinning and spinning'...i mean the site load but not "quite completely"...aparently NET waits for the page to stop loading but Nasdaq keeps pulling live data via jscript or so which results in timeout...

Comment: that too but i meant I can't even load the page on nasdaq from chrome so it may even be my internet connection, ps - if you can add it as an answer so i can acceptt it, 10x.

Comment: Just tried what Pepper claimed...got "500 server error"...go figure. I may now play a bit with the browser headers if the issue is really 'server being picky'.

Comment: OK, finally...think I found a solution?? Now everything works on Nasdaq! But the issue seems to be my poor debugging choice :). I am using MessageBox which seems to block everything...the flow of the program, so I just try to debug via textbox and now it shows 0_0? Also, I just changed 2-3 headers + added other protocols (ssl3/tls1) so this may be the case too - will post the working thing below...

Answer (score 0):

```
  /// button + textbox are added to the windows form, you also need to add  
  ///Using System.IO; Using System.Net; Using System.Net.Security at the very beginning...

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
              ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;



              string bumb = "https://nasdaq.com";


                   HttpWebRequest requestHtm = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(bumb);
                   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };



               //    requestHtm.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                   requestHtm.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                   requestHtm.KeepAlive = true;
               //    requestHtm.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
               //    requestHtm.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
               //    requestHtm.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "en-gb,en;q=0.5";
               //    requestHtm.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset] = "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
                   requestHtm.Timeout = 150000;
                   //requestHtm.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
                   requestHtm.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Mobile Safari/537.36";

                 //requestHtm.Method = "GET"; 



                   using (HttpWebResponse responseHtm = (HttpWebResponse)requestHtm.GetResponse())
                   {
                       StreamReader r = new StreamReader(responseHtm.GetResponseStream());

                       string text1 = r.ReadToEnd();


                       textBox1.Text = text1;


                   }
    }
```